# Asp .Net element onclick

Tags: asp.net, onclick

I'd need this to work.
I have to associate to the following line of code an onclick event.
I don't have a button and I can't use one. 
I want to use this list item to make the onclick method work

```
<li><a runat="server" visible="false" id="logout" onclick="logout_Click">Log Out</a></li>
```

C# code:

```
protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {                        
     Session.Clear();
     Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explore your self about `Client Side Event` and `Sever Side Event` first.

`<a>` anchor tag is an HTML tag and for server-side call -  you need `PageMethod` or `ajax call`.

- You can use [asp:HtmlAnchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor(v=vs.110).aspx) asp tag. It is alternate of HTML `<a>` tag.

HTML Code -

```
<li><asp:HtmlAnchor OnServerClick="logout_Click" /></li>
```

C# Code -

```
protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {                        
     Session.Clear();
     Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
 }
```

Comment: it was about the OnServerClick, I used onclick instead. Thanks for the explaination. It works now

Answer (score 3):

Try below :

```
<a id="logout"         onserverclick="logout_Click"         runat="server">
```

Comment: Thanks it works! but the other answer was more exhaustive. Plus he answered before you =) I gave you a big thumb up

Answer (score 0):

```
<a runat="server" visible="false" id="logout" onclick="logout_Click()">Log Out</a>
```

you forgot the parenthesis :D

Comment: btw why the visibility is set to false? maybe that's why you can't see it?

Comment: oh well it's a normal website, I have a login label, I click it and it goes to "/Login.aspx", then I login, so the loginlable.Visible="false"; and logout.Visible="true"; cause I'm already logged in. Now I have to associate logout with a C# method. Anyway, when I log in the label becomes visible. Also if it's invisible you're still able to see it. hmm :/